# Where to download glassfish-3.0.1-b22 source code archive

Tags: tortoisesvn, glassfish-3

Can anyone provide a link to a downloadable archive of the source code for GlassFish 3.0.1-b22?

I have tried using TortoiseSVN to checkout this directory without success,

https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn

The error is,

```
Checkout from https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
OPTIONS of 'https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn': could not connect to 
server (https://svn.java.net)
```

I do not have access to the svn command.

Answer (score 1):

The url should be

https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/tags/3.0.1-b22/

Just verified, this one works.

Comment: Thanks but I want to download the entire source code so I can debug into GF. Any ideas.

Comment: What do you mean?  You want to download it as a zipfile?

Comment: Yes. A zip file would be perfect.

Comment: @janek I don't think it exists, anyways just transferring with tortoise once will also give you a full local copy, identical to unzipping a downloaded archive.  If you want you can always zip up the downloaded tree.

Comment: As noted the TortoiseSVN checkout does not work for me so I do not have this option.

Comment: The URL is gave is not identical to the one you tried and this one I tried myself with tortoise, it works.

Comment: Thanks. I might have a firewall issue so I have +1'd your answer. Thanks.